# email received from mobile or browser

Tags: email, mobile, browser

Is there any way to know from which environment an email is coming? (whether it is from a mobile device or a web browser?). I would like to use a server side program for this. If you have any other ideas, please suggest them.

Thanks
Vego

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the client that is generating the email to distinguish between the browser/mobile being the source and add some extended headers to let the receivers know about this information.

If you are the author / user of such a client generating the email, you can configure the extended header appropriately.